Build error from node_module package next_intl
Using next and next_intl for localization, I faced this problem while running the build command.
 pnpm run build

> next build

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.5
  - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types  .Failed to compile.

./node_modules/.pnpm/next-intl@3.17.2_next@14.2.5_@babel+core@7.24.9_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1/node_modules/next-intl/dist/types/src/navigation/react-client/createSharedPathnamesNavigation.d.ts:4:57
Type error: Type parameter declaration expected.

  2 | import { Locales } from '../../routing/types';
  3 | import { SharedNavigationRoutingConfigInput } from '../shared/config';
> 4 | export default function createSharedPathnamesNavigation<const AppLocales extends Locales>(input?: SharedNavigationRoutingConfigInput<AppLocales>): {
    |                                                         ^
  5 |     Link: (props: Omit<Omit<Omit<Omit<Omit<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, keyof {  
  6 |         href: string | import("url").UrlObject;
  7 |         as?: string | import("url").UrlObject;
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

How to solve this that should not get an error while building, this package works perfectly without any error in dev mode.

This was not related to next-intl it is related to ts version and lower version of 5 doesn't work you should use higher version.
